# Imported SSIS package fails if imported with SSMS on the SQL server, but works when imported from a remote PC

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis

I am facing a strange issue on SQL Server 2017 Enterprise edition running in AWS on EC2.

When we are on the SQL server and we import an SSIS package using the locally installed SSMS connected to Integration Services it is successful. But, the package fails to run with an error:

> ```
> The binary code for the script is not found. 
> Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
> ```

However, if we perform the exact same procedure from a remotely connected Windows 10 PC using the SSMS that is installed on the PC, the package will run properly.

Both the server and the Windows workstation are running SSMS 17.9.1. Comparing versions in Help -> About shows the exact same version numbers on everything. The same domain user is performing the procedure and that user is a domain admin and SQL Sysadmin.

This makes no sense. Is there another component being used I am unaware of? Any ideas?

Comment: On both machines, open a command prompt and look for isdeploymentwizard.exe `C:\>dir /s /b isdeploymentwizard.exe` and also check `where isdeploymentwizard.exe` My suspicion is that the the deployment tool - isdeploymentwizard.exe is upgrading the package prior to deployment on the local scenario.

Comment: @billinkc Looks like a difference for sure. I notice two things. On the local PC there is only a 32-bit version. On the server there are both 32 and 64 bit. if I compare the 32-bit versions I see that they are different. The PC is 14.0.3026.27 and the server is 14.0.3238.1. I'll continue to look in to this, but open to ideas.

Comment: 32 vs 64 deployment shouldn't be an issue, nor minor point differences. I'd be looking for something like (AWS box has it in 150, remote computer has 130,140, & 150 - in that order)

Comment: And so why this major version stuff matters - SSIS is always forwards compatible. I can take a 2005 SSIS package and if the 2019 tooling (editor, deployment, or package runner) uses that package, the *first* thing it does is upgrade to that version's standard and then performs edit/deploy/run task. For deployments, it was *hi-larious!* when we'd unwittingly use newer tooling as the ispac (zip) file is going to get stored into the database just fine. It's only when the package runs, that the tooling will notice this is incompatible with current

Comment: 2016+ addressed backwards compatibility but in a hamhanded way. The Editor can change the target of the project but running packages is still done by having a dtexec.exe per version of SQL Server (as it's tightly bound to SQL Server libraries)

Comment: @billinkc Ok. I appreciate the info. I can only assume we are on the wrong track. I've read that isdeploymentwizard.exe is used during project deployment models. This is a package deployment model I am referring to. I've used process monitor on both the server and workstation. isdeploymentwizard.exe is never executed during any import process. Thanks again.

Comment: The crash ate my comment but look at `dtutil.exe` as that is the package deployment model tool - same caveats about compatibility. The packages in msdb.dbo.syspackages are not zipped so you can easily look at the values of the deployed packages `SELECT *, CAST(CAST(s.packagedata AS varbinary(MAX)) AS nvarchar(MAX)) FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages AS S`  Check your PackageFormatVersion and compare that to maybe the packageformat value in the sysssispackages table.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the info. You've been very helpful. I've had a chance to investigate further. I don't see any usage of `dtutil.exe` in my Procmon listing. I see a lot of .NET usage. So, I made sure both systems were running the same version of .NET, with no fix. I looked at the packagedata on the server and compared. Interestingly, I see slightly different binary code for most scripts, but the binary code for the script that causes the error is completely missing. I'll have to investigate this more tomorrow.

Comment: To clarify, the dtutil.exe is only going to be active while you're deploying the package  into the msdb. The package running utility is dtexec.exe whether you're using the classic package deployment model or the project deployment model. And for completeness, you can run SSIS packages without dtexec.exe if you write a custom application.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks again. I posted an answer to the problem. Yes, I understand that I was looking for dtutil.exe during import. However, dtutil.exe was not used during import. Long story short, the source code for the script was failing to compile and I was not receiving any error indicating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I found in regards to this issue.

First, I exported the broken package from the server after importing it. I also exported the working package from the server after importing it. I compared the two files side by side and quickly discovered that the script within our package where the errors occurred was missing it's binary data in the `BinaryItem` element. I was also able to look directly at the package data on the server using the query:

```
SELECT id
    ,NAME
    ,CAST(CAST(packagedata AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) PackageXML
    ,description
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages]
```

The missing binary code indicated to me that the script was not being properly compiled during import.

After wasting a lot of time trying to find out why, I realized that the script was fairly simple so I should take a look in the script to see what was in there that might cause the import to fail.

I discovered a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` which is part of the Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies installed with Microsoft Office. On the SQL server, Microsoft Office is not installed. As a result, the .DLL file related to this reference is missing on the SQL server.

Removing the faulty, and unneeded reference solved the issue. I was able to confirm with Process Monitor that the server was looking for this .DLL file during import and not able to find it.

Apparently, if this happens during import there is no indication of the failure. Long story short, the error message was accurate. The binary code was missing. That was a result of a failure to compile the source code during import.